# Knot polynomial of composite knot

Tags: knot-theory

This is a question from  “An introduction to knot theory” $(GTM 57)$

If we  tie  two  knots  on  the  same  piece  of string,  the result is  called a composite knot. Prove that the Alexander polynomial of a  composite knot is the product of the polynomials of the constituent knots.

How can I consider this question? It there are any other reference for this question?

Comment: The place to start is with the definition of the Alexander polynomial and/or with whatever method you have learned for computing it.

Comment: So, have you made a start?

Comment: I think I can use Wirtinger presentation to find the group presentation of two knot and add a relation as the line connect two knot. I don’t know how to find that relation to relate two knots.

Comment: Is the Alexander polynomial defined in terms of these presentations you mention?

Comment: This is the first step. The definition of Alexandra polynomial(P123) should start from Alexandra matrix(P100).  When you find the Alexander matrix, there is a invariant called elementary Ideal, which has also has the modern name Flitting ideal， which is the ideal generated by determinant of $(n-k)\times (n-k)$. We say it $E_k$ become a chain of ideal. Then we can use the Alexandra matrix to find the knot polynomial which is the g.c.d of all $(n-k)\times (n-k)$ submatrix. This is the link of book https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/crowfox.pdf.

Comment: This is a very odd book and uses a lot of outdated notations. I think it is good to start with how to find the presentation of two composite knots. How to add a relation to connect two knots.

Comment: Well, it may be difficult to get to where you want to go starting from that. But maybe the matrix for the composite knot breaks up in some natural way into two blocks, one for each of the two original knots, so you can write each of those determinants as a product of two determinants, one for each block of the matrix. Sorry, I can't do any better than that.